# Solving planning problems

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to the AI/ algorithm field and is currently trying to solve a problem, I've so far only implemented an A* path finding on a 2d grid array before.

The problem goes like this:

Consider a class of 40 students (20f,20m) with varying height and have their own seating preferences(row,column, or both), and a classroom 50 seats, each student must occupy a seat and the seats are being laid out as follow:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]   [ ] [ ] [ ]

              [ WHITE BOARD ]
```

To ideally seat them, a scoring graph has been elected:

1. No students seating directly in front : +4 points
2. Student seating directly in front is shorter by at least 2cm :+4 points
3. Student seating beside you is of opposite sex: +8 points
4. 4 students of the same gender occupying a column: -10 points
5. A column with ascending height from the whiteboard: +20 points
6. Seating according to individual preferences: +2 points

The goal is to score the maximum points possible.

My idea is to use A* modified to suit the current problem:

Starting: all students unseated

Path cost: increment of points after the transition

Goal: all students seated

The problem here is, the maximum points possible is not known, and I can foresee that there might be scenario where the program fail to plan ahead, (the program might pick +8 and then followed by +4, where as a better way will be to pick +2 then followed by +20), I am aware that I can look for certain depth, say a depth of 5. This invites another question: what's the depth that I should use? I don't really want to visit all possible states.

1.How hard is this kind of problem? (from a scale of solving maze to solving chess/go)

2.Am I on the right path of solving this problem?

Comment: does the algorithm know the distribution of height and sex of the students?

Comment: A* probably isn't a good approach. At least i cannot wrap my head around what the heuristic would look like.

Comment: A* seems like a square peg in a round hole for this problem. A* is about minimizing costs, while you're trying to maximize gains, and it doesn't allow negative costs. I don't see a good way to turn this into a problem of minimizing opportunity costs or a good way to fix the problem of scores going both up and down.

Comment: @user2357112 It's usually straightforward to state all constraints negatively. For example: instead of "Student seating directly in front is shorter by at least 2cm: +4", state "Student seating directly in front is not shorter by at least 2cm: -4".

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: Looking at the scoring criteria again, I'm not sure about my concerns. I thought applying such a translation to this problem would lead to a cost structure where moves tend to all have roughly equal, high costs dominated by all the bonuses you're not getting, leading to a tendency for the search to degenerate to breadth-first. On a second reading of the scoring criteria, it doesn't look like the bonuses work that way. You have a lot more experience with optimization problems than I do, so you probably have a better sense of how things work.

Comment: I'm with those who are skeptical about A* for this. To me, it's more a question of how solutions are distributed in the space; I don't see A* rapidly getting out of local minima in this case. Seems to me more like a simulated annealing approach might work, or a GA. Best might be to recast it as bin-packing and use the pseudo-polynomial approximation approach. With integer costs / weights, you should be safe.

Comment: How would Rule 3 score [M]-[F]-[M]? Would it be 2*8 because there are two graph edges? Would it be 3*8 because each person is seated beside (at least) one of the opp gender? Or would it be 4*8 because the middle person is seated beside two people of the opp gender?

Comment: How does Rule 6 score when a person has both a row and a column preference? Do they get +4 if they satisy both? Do they get +2 if they satisfy only one of the two preferences?

Answer (score 2):

Constraint 6 look like it implies that this problem might be NP-complete or NP-hard. That means: the A* algorithm won't work (well) on this, because it's impossible (unless P = NP) to create a good admissible heuristic function. *Admissible* means that the heuristic function should always underestimate or equal the score of the optimal solution, it never overestimates.
If you need to include constraint 6, I'd recommend to use algorithms such as Tabu Search, Simulated Annealing or Late Acceptance, which work well on similar use cases, such as [Dinner party seating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L98J6HhSCXQ) and [Course scheduling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4meWIhPRVn8).

Without constraint 6, I think something as simple as a [First Fit Decreasing](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#firstFitDecreasing) algorithm can be designed to be optimal:

1. all even seats go to females, all odd seats go to males (if there's not enough seats for 1 gender, add the overflow in the other gender). Schedule both independently. While scheduling 1 gender, ignore the seats of the other gender.
2. Sort all students in 1 gender group according to height. Assign them one by one in decreasing height.
3. For each step, assign the largest unassigned student to the unassigned seat at the highest row (and secondarily the most on the left)

Constraint 2 might still not be optimal this way though... you might still need to apply some Tabu Search or Late Acceptance on it.

Comment: How would constraint 6 make it NP complete? Wouldn't the number of states be finite?

Comment: All NP-complete problems have a finite number of states (and many NP-hard problems too). But their number of states grows exponentially and there's no known polynomial time way to wade through them to find the optimal one.

Comment: As for constraint 6 making it NP-complete, that's my educated guess. A formal description of the constraint and a formal relaxation to an NP-complete problem can prove/disprove that.